# Can't change variable value angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using angularjs with the implementation "Angular Material" (here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/)

I'm using the SideNav component: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.sidenav to open a lateral container on click in a menu link. It's working right now... But when i click the menu item i should change the value of a boolean variable from false to true.. This doesn't happen. I don't know exactly why. In my controller i have this part of code:

```
$scope.toggleRight = buildToggler('right');
        $scope.myBoolean = false;
        /**
         * Build handler to open/close a SideNav; when animation finishes
         * report completion in console
         */
        function buildToggler(navID) {
            var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
                $mdSidenav(navID)
                    .toggle()
                    .then(function () {
                        $log.debug("toggle " + navID + " is done");
                    });
            },300);
            return debounceFn;
        };
        $scope.close = function () {
            $mdSidenav('right').close()
                .then(function () {
                    $log.debug("close RIGHT is done");
                });
        };
```

That it's the part to open and close the container. Then in my html

```
                <li>
                    <a data-ng-click="myBoolean = true;">
                        Open the container
                    </a>
                </li>
```

So, if the variable was "false" now should be "true" when the item of the menu is clicked. But still remains false.. What's wrong?

Comment: How are you checking if that variable is still false? I can't see classContent anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Sorry Man, corrected now.

Comment: I still don't see code using myBoolean. You set it false in the controller, then set it true from the view. How are you checking it's not staying true?

Answer (score 0):

//Just write down the below function i controller

```
$scope.openContainer = function () {
    $scope.myBoolean = true;
}
```

//and in View change below

```
<li>
    <a data-ng-click="openContainer()">Open the container</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the variable in this way:

```
<li>
                <a data-ng-click="$parent.myBoolean = true;">
                    Open the container
                </a>
            </li>
```

Use $parent property. I believe the sidenav component has its own scope and the link is inside the sidenav component. So in order to access the variable in your scope you need to go one level upper (in the parent scope)